# Reading files and storing: Python

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to read a file wich contains a tuple, and then store said tuple. But the output I got was said tuple in a string, with \n in the end. I tried to get rid of it (I need it to be a tuple) like this:

```
    def tupleFromFile(file):
        f = open(file, 'r')
        line = f.readline()
        line = line.replace(' '' ', '').replace(' \n'' ', '')
        f.close()
    return line
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the example file (if it is in text form) with input data?

Comment: the text is something like (((1, 45, 6), (2, 98), (45,)), ((72, 43), (54, 7)))... @BudoZindovic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the string-tuple data be stored in variable line. You can interpret them as tuple like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
tuple_line = make_tuple(line)
```

Also, there is a bug in the code you posted, and the correct function should be:

```
def tupleFromFile(file):
    f = open(file, 'r')
    line = f.readline()
    line = line.replace(' '' ', '').replace(' \n'' ', '')
    f.close()
    return line
```